# Только начал изучение C++ пишу код с сайта в Visual Studio 2022. Выдает ошибки

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2022

[image: 1 #include 2 using namespace std; 3 4 int main() 5 { 6 setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus"); 7 cout << "Мы создали первый проект в MVS2022" << endl; 8 return 0; 9 }]
Только начал изучение C++ пишу код с сайта в Visual Studio 2022. Выдает ошибки. Как их решить?

Comment: Первая ошибка главная, остальные - следствие. Проверяйте наличие библиотеки, тип проэкта правильность путей. Этого скрина не достаточно, что бы дать точнее подсказки. Ещё... Программа должна быть в c-файле, а не в h-файле. h - это заголовочный файл.

Comment: Наверное, у вас неверно установлен VStudio, и он не знает, где искать стандартные заголовочные файлы.